# Could x * y == y when x != 1 and y != 0?

Tags: c#, ieee-754

If `x` and `y` are IEEE 754 floating point numbers (single or double precision), could we ever have

```
x * y == y
```

where `x != 1` and `y != 0` (and nor is `y` equal to `+inf`, `-inf`, or `nan`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; this might happen when you get near to extreme small factors and/or [denormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number).

Example:

```
float x = 1.0000001f;
float y = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000001f;
Console.WriteLine("x: " + x);
Console.WriteLine("y: " + y);
Console.WriteLine(x * y == y);
Console.WriteLine("x*y: " + (x * y));
```

yields

```
x: 1.0000001
y: 1E-41
True
x*y: 1E-41
```

([dotnetfiddle with .NET Core 3.1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/toVskt))

All numbers are well-defined, but the multiplication cannot be carried out at this precision.

Fun fact: Running the same with .NET Framework 4.7.2 yields the following:

```
x: 1
y: 9.999666E-42
False
x*y: 9.999666E-42
```

([dotnetfiddle with .NET Framework 4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4aVyxC))

So, the implementations behave differently for very small numbers.